# Is it possible to get the data from a formset as a list of dictionaries before it is validated in Django?

Tags: django, django-forms

I know that after validation, `formset.cleaned_data` gives a list of dictionaries of a formset. Now, I need to obtain the same list before it is validated. Is this possible?

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    formset = SampleFormSet(request.POST, prefix='sample')
    print(formset...?) #Should print all the data in the formset
    if formset.is_valid():
        ...
    else:
        formset... #Modify it
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just checked the documentation, and I do not think it is possible at the moment.

[Source code of formsets in Django 2.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/_modules/django/forms/formsets/)

[Documentation of formsets in Django 3.2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/formsets/)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible.

There are two path.

First : On views you can do some like this:

```
def my_func(request):   
       if request.method == 'POST':
          #your var before validate
          my_var = request.POST.get("your_field")
          # to do you code.
```

Another option is put on your method clean() in your form.

Like this.

```
 def clean(self):
    #your var before validate
    your_var = self.cleaned_data["your_field"]
```

Comment: Oh I think I worded it incorrectly. Is it possible to obtain all the formset's fields like a list of dictionaries just like `formset.cleaned_data`?

Comment: I got it. So, why not get data inside the formset using `def clean(self)` ? It's doesn't work in your case?

Comment: Because I need to check the data outside `def clean(self)` since `def clean(self)` returns an error if a field is not populated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get acces to row data though `formset.data` (returns QueryDict).